# TypeScript - what type is setInterval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

If I'd like to assign a type to a variable that will later be assigned a setInterval like so:

```
this.autoSaveInterval = setInterval(function(){
      if(this.car.id){
        this.save();
      }
      else{
        this.create();
      }
    }.bind(this), 50000);
```

What type should be assigned to this.autosaveInterval vairable?

Comment: public autoSaveInterval  :number;

Comment: You don't need to specify a type; `autoSaveInterval` will infer its type from the return value of the `setInterval` call. In browser platforms this is `number`, but in node.js it's a Timer

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/842

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Late to the party, but the best type (especially since the type is opaque, we only care that we can pass it to `clearInterval()` later) might be the automatically deduced one, ie. something like:

```
ReturnType<typeof setInterval>
```

Comment: Man, this should definitely have been picked as the correct answer. "number" doesn't work, especially in angular

Comment: I'm joining the party, number didn't work for me either, thank you!!

Comment: Cleanest way of solving the problem, and works in all environments

Comment: Wow, didn't know about ReturnType. That's huge!

Comment: ChatGPT couldn't figure this one out, so thank you for this.

Comment: It should also be noted that according to the `@types/node` package, v16 `setInterval` returns `NodeJS.Timer`, while v18 `setInterval` returns `NodeJS.Timeout`. This answer's method is superior for migration concerns because using `ReturnType` will always be correct.

Answer (score 125):

The type depends on which function you are going to use there are 2 overloads, the return type is marked in red bounding-box :

[image]

In order to use the one which returns number, please use :

```
window.setInterval(...)
```

Comment: Could you share the website or book you got this reference?Thanks.

Comment: Hi this is not  a book you can find it if you working with visual studio and search for implementation .

Comment: In browsers environment, it should be `window.setInterval` and the return type is number as it is.

Comment: Yes this worked for me and I set the type as `let intervalId: number | undefined = undefined;`

Answer (score 48):

The type is number;

```js
private autoSaveInterval: number = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('123');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @gfels Because setInterval return that representing the ID value of the timer that is set. You can use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer. It's not a function because you are not assigning the function handler to it, **you are assigning the result/return value of a function to it.**

Comment: If you are using TypeScript, and you get compiler errors because somehow the NodeJS.Timer type is inferred: change to window.setInterval to specify you're not using node and the DOM type should be used, which is number indeed.

Comment: It's not number in node.js

Answer (score 27):

I believe its NodeJS.Timeout and widow.setInterval is number:

```
const nodeInterval: NodeJS.Timeout = setInterval(() => {
  // do something
}, 1000);

const windowInterval: number = window.setInterval(() => {
  // do something
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The type it's not NodeJS.Timeout but **NodeJS.Timer**

Comment: What is the NodeJs type? where it comes from?

Answer (score 3):

As it's mentioned in other answers, the type of `setInterval` is either `:number` or `:NodeJS.Timer`.

I would like to extend the scope of the answer a little bit if anyone is looking to use `setInterval` with **React and Typescript**

```
const Clock: React.FC = () => {
  const secondsRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timer>();

  useEffect(() => {
    secondsRef.current = setInterval(() => { // type is taken correctly and no errors
      // do your stuff...
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* your jsx... */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

Hope someone will find my answer helpful... happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, it is treated as an opaque handle, it isn't worth struggling with types just to satisfy the windows vs node environments. Just use this and be done with it:

```
let timerHandle: any = null;

function start() {
  timerHandle = setInterval(...);
}

export function stop() {
  if (timerHandle) clearInterval(timerHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although i was able to run the app with

```
id: number;

this.id = setInterval(...)
```

a test will inform you that Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'
so i went with https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681620/18975994 approach, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type for setInterval: NodeJS.Timer

Answer (score -2):

Use typeof operator to find data type of any variable like this:

> typeof is an unary operator that is placed before a single operand
>   which can be of any type. Its value is a string that specifies the
>   type of operand.

```js
var variable1 = "Hello";
var autoSaveInterval;

this.autoSaveInterval = setInterval(function(){
      if(this.car.id){
        this.save();
      }
      else{
        this.create();
      }
    }.bind(this), 50000);
    
console.log("1st: " + typeof(variable1))
console.log("2nd: " + typeof(autoSaveInterval ))
```

Comment: This is not helping with Typescript definitions

Comment: This does not contain any reference to the original question regarding TypeScript types