# How do I specify the type of setInterval function in typeScript using React useState() hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a timer app using `react` and `typeScript`. 
In the Project I need to store the instance of `setInterval()` in `useState()` hook which I'll use to clear the `setInterval()` instance.

My timer instance look like this.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState<NodeJS.Timer>();
```

I'm using this function to clear the timer instance

```js
  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    setTimerOn(false);
  };
```

But the issue with this approach is that inside the stop function `clearInterval` is showing an error because the type of timer is `NodeJS.timer | undefined` and only `NodeJS.timer` type is allowed in `clearInterval` function.

To remove the undefined type from the `useState` I have created an dummy `setInterval` instace and use it as the initial value in `useState` as shown in the image below.

[image]
[image]

However I'm wondering whether my approach is correct or it is just a hacky solution? I want to know a proper approach for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - what type is f.e. setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376589/typescript-what-type-is-f-e-setinterval)

Comment: You can just do a falsy check before: `timer && clearInterval(timer)`

Comment: @Terry falsy check will now solve the issue. My main issue is that initially when I wanted to store the instance of timer in useState hook, there is no value inside the useState which makes the type of timer undefined. So, when I use `clearInterval` it expect a type of NodeJS.timer but the type is undefined.

Comment: I’d say creating an empty timer is actually a hack and less efficient, because the browser needs to keep track of the ID of another timer. Just settle for undefined and then do a check before attempting to use the value.