# Having issue with implicitly has type 'any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function below that works in Mantine perfectly:

```
useEffect(() => {
      let interval = null;
      if (isActive) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
        }, 1000);
      } else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [isActive, seconds]);
```

However, when I moved it to MUI I get the error below. I know it's not related to the library but to some setting. Somehow I can't figure it out.

Variable 'interval' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.ts(7034)

```
    useEffect(() => {
      let interval = null;
      if (isActive) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
        }, 1000);
      } else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [isActive, seconds]);
```

Comment: Does MUI use typescript? Because this is an issue with the type of your `interval` variable not having a type explicitly set. This by itself is fine, TS (TypeScript) doesn't actually force you to set a type for all variables. But you have to either change your linting settings for TS to ignore this error (or provide a warning instead of an error), or provide the type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681620) for the type you want to set

Comment: `let interval: number | null = null;`

Answer (score 0):

```
let interval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.